# Find substring ignoring returns

Tags: python, string, substring

How can I remove a (substring) from the beginning of a larger string while ignoring returns? For example, the substring may look like this:

```
mysqldump --host="ssh.example.com" --user="jack" --password="3kg%39$(*kdsk#"
```

The larger string will look like this (notice the substring at the beginning and some returns throughout):

```
mysqldump --host="ssh.examp
le.com" --user="jack" --password="3
kg%39$(*kdsk#"
-- more stuff that needs to remain --
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
adipiscing elit. Qua tu etiam inprudens
utebare non numquam. Sed haec quidem
```

How can I find and remove the substring from the larger string such that the result will look like this:

```
-- more stuff that needs to remain --
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
adipiscing elit. Qua tu etiam inprudens
utebare non numquam. Sed haec quidem
```

With the substring removed from the beginning.

Comment: How about `replace` ? http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm

Comment: I don't think that would work as the string changes with the returns, correct?

Comment: I have no idea what your statement/question means. Sorry. Can you elaborate? The *input* to the replace function does not change. The *output* of the function might of course be different from the input, if the `replace` function did in fact replace something.

Comment: My apologies, I'm not being very clear. Does my edit clarify the question well enough?

Comment: We need to know exactly how the substring you are looking for CAN look like and/or how we would know where "Alot more lines and data" start.

Comment: @timgeb How does it read now?

Comment: are the first and second substring always separated by the first blank line?

Comment: @timgeb No, it won't be. I will update the question accordingly.

Comment: We can't help you further if you don't tell us how we would know when the second substring starts. you only said how the first substring MAY look like, and that the second substring may contain basically anything. For all we know, there's no way to differentiate between the two.

Comment: @timgeb I will always know exactly what the first string looks like and how long it is. The second string will have that first string at the beginning, but with returns randomly scattered throughout. As for the second string, that could look like anything after the end of the first string.

Answer (score 1):

Old answer:

Hopefully I understood your specs right. Is this what you are asking?

```
>>> s = '''mysqldump --host="ssh.examp
... le.com" --user="jack" --password="3
... kg%39$(*kdsk#"'''
>>> s = s.replace('\n','').partition(' ')[-1]
>>> s
'--host="ssh.example.com" --user="jack" --password="3kg%39$(*kdsk#"'
```

Updated answer:

> I will always know exactly what the first string looks like and how long it is. The second string will have that first string at the beginning, but with returns randomly scattered throughout. As for the second string, that could look like anything after the end of the first string.

In that case, I'd suggest something like this.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'mysqldump --host="ssh.examp\nle.com" --user="jack" --passw\nwo\nr\n\nd\n=\n"3\nkg%39$(*kdsk#"this is the stuff\nthat"needs"to remain!'
>>> s[re.search(r'd\n*=\n*"[^"]*"', s).end():]
'this is the stuff\nthat"needs"to remain!'
```

Comment: No, that appears to remove all returns from s... s should be a much larger string with the command at the beginning and an unknown number of returns scattered throughout.

Comment: @yajtheman in that case, I don't understand your question. Please make it clearer what you want to do, with an example of the input and expected output.

Comment: Instead of `str.find()` and a slice, use `str.partition(' ')[-1]`.

Comment: Almost, but I don't know beforehand what the string looks like. `r'password="[^"]+"'` is matching the password part of the specific substring given, right? It seems to me that I just need someway to match a substring while ignoring new lines. Sorry I haven't been very clear, and thanks for all your help.

Comment: You are driving me crazy. A moment ago you said you know exactly what the first string will look like, except for the random newlines.

Comment: Sorry, I meant I know exactly what the string will look like before checking for the substring. Not that the string will always be the same... I don't know, I'm about ready to give up.